# Installing software for Windows: WSL2 vs downloading installer

Tags: windows, installation, wsl2

I started using WSL2 for Windows a while ago. However, I was wondering what the best practices for installations are.

Traditionally, many software for Windows requires you to download an installer while `*nix`, which includes WSL2, lets you install software by running a few commands.

Here are some examples:

*Git*:

- To install Git on Windows, you need to [download an installer](https://git-scm.com/download/win) first.
- To install Git on `*nix`, you just need to run [a few simple commands](https://git-scm.com/download/linux).

*Rust*:

- To install Rust on Windows, you need to install [a few different things](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html#installing-rustup-on-windows).
- To install Rust on `*nix`, you just need to run a [command](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-01-installation.html#installing-rustup-on-linux-or-macos).

Since WSL2 can run most, if not all, `*nix` commands, I prefer to install them in a `*nix` manner rather than installing additional software.

**Questions**:

- Are there any disadvantages of installing software via WSL2?
- In which scenario would it be better to install via the "traditional" Windows method?

I suppose I'm wondering if it's just a matter of preference or if there is a clear advantage/disadvantage between the two methods.

Comment: Those commands would install Rust and Git within WSL which is running a Linux kernel.  What exactly is your question? You can't really install Windows software from within WSL, but there is also [WinGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) that is native to supported versions of Windows 10 and 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose I'm wondering if it's just a matter of preference or if there is a clear advantage/disadvantage between the two methods.

There's just so much "It depends" in there based on:

- Your workflow
- The tool in question
- And yes, your preferences

There's no way to answer that question in a "general" sense, unfortunately.

> Are there any disadvantages of installing software via WSL2?

At least that one has a "general" answer.  One of WSL2's biggest limitations currently is regarding performance when accessing the Windows filesystem (e.g. `/mnt/c/`, et.al.).  If the files that you are working with are in Windows, then you may experience *drastic* slowdowns when accessing them from WSL2 tools.

For instance, as I mention in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/11810933) on the topic, checking out the WSL2 kernel repo from Github from WSL2 onto the Windows filesystem took around 8 minutes, vs. a few seconds to do it directly to the ext4 filesystem in WSL.

> In which scenario would it be better to install via the "traditional" Windows method?

While there are a lot of "it depends" to this as well, based on the tool, in general I'd say:

- When you are developing using Windows native code/libraries
- When you need to access files in a Windows filesystem
- When the Windows tool is designed to work with WSL (e.g. VSCode, Neovide, and others)
- When it is a graphical application -- Typically the Windows equivalent will have better integration and performance than using the X/Wayland equivalent under WSLg.

Comment: Perfect! This is the type of answer that I was looking for.